# Send an image to nodejs api by nextjs api folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, form-data, formidable

I a
I have a file instance which i got from formidable library. It looks like this

```
photo: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 16648,
    path: 'public/upload_1.jpg',
    name: 'test.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: 2021-07-08T11:22:05.804Z,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: 'public/upload_1.jpg',
      fd: null,
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      autoClose: true,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 16648,
      closed: false
    }
  }
```

Now i need to pass this image to an external nodejs api which is expecting the image in

```
req.file('photo')
```

format.

Pls help how to send the above instance to nodejs api.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serverside FormData and fs.createReadStream worked like a charm to me.